# AutoHotKey script paste text with new line without pressing Enter

Tags: autohotkey

I need to do a very simple thing: create a shortcut that paste a text with new line inside, like this

```
first line
second line
```

I know I can do that using send, sendinput or sendinput {text}

```
#NoEnv ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
#SingleInstance force
SendMode Input ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir% ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

^!q::
  Send first line `nsecond line`n
return

^!w::
  SendInput first line `nsecond line`n
return

^!e::
  SendInput {text}first line `nsecond line`n
return
```

I saw that it can be risky because, in all these ways, the new line can act as an Enter command, and I want to avoid this behavior.

So I tried using clipboard:

```
#NoEnv ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
#SingleInstance force
SendMode Input ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir% ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

^!r::
  string = first line `nsecond line`n
  prevClipboard := ClipboardAll
  Clipboard := string
  ClipWait, 1, 1 ; Wait for the clipboard to contain the copied text.
  Send ^v
  Clipboard := prevClipboard ; keep previous cliboard content
return
```

In my personal computer it works, but it doesn't work in another case, where I use a portable AHK in a very slow virtual machine, the first time it works, the second time in only pastes the actual Clipboard content

Is there a way to do this?

Test I made to verify that my shortcut press the enter key:
choose a file in file explorer, pressed Shift + Canc, this shows a popup "are you sure you want to permanently delete?"
and then pressed my ahk shortcut, it acted like an Enter key and deleted the file

Comment: I don't think this is possible in the general case? (the other program might be arbitrarily laggy)

Comment: Yes it doesn't seem to be possible. See [load - AutoHotKey Copy file to clipboard and paste - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984001/autohotkey-copy-file-to-clipboard-and-paste) -- the only answer there recommends waiting for 2s.

Comment: There's also `ControlSetText`

Answer (score 2):

You're likely setting the old clipboard back too quick.
To make a reliable script like this, it's required to wait a bit before setting the old clipboard. The app to which you send the paste action can also choose to process the clipboard in its own way, which is when this problem becomes especially apparent.

Also, your first `ClipWait` isn't doing anything. You have to clear the clipboard before using `ClipWait`, otherwise it's of no use since the clipboard already contains something. Also, I'm not 100% sure a `ClipWait` is needed here, but it wont hurt at least.

Here's a possibly fixed script:

```
^!r::
  string := "first line `nsecond line`n"
  
  /*
  ;continuation sections are cool
  string := "
  (LTrim
  first line
  second line
  
  )"
  */
  
  prevClipboard := ClipboardAll
  Clipboard := "" ;empty the clipboard first
  Clipboard := string
  ClipWait, 1, 1 ; Wait for the clipboard to contain the copied text.
  SendInput, ^v
  Sleep, 500 ;500ms is hopefully more than enough
  Clipboard := prevClipboard ; keep previous cliboard content
return
```

<sup>[(Documentation for continuation)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#continuation)</sup>